# Есть ли в си возможность чтения из файла по пакетам?

Tags: c, unix

Мне нужно получить stdout одной программы на с в другой программе на с, я использую для этого pipe. Возможно ли читать stout в том же формате, в котором его записывали. Т.е программа сначала записала 3 байта, потом 5, потом 3 и другая программа прочитала в той же последовательности, т.е сначала 3, потом 5, потом 3 или тутне обойтись без составления своего алгоритма?

Comment: Нет, сочиняйте свой протокол...

Comment: Да, возможно. Это самый примитивный IPC, который предоставляют UNIX-совместимые системы.

Comment: Можно. Только для записи используйте write() (или для FILE не забывайте fflush)

Comment: @avp в write не предусмотрено никакого деления на пакеты. Более того, write имеет право вообще обрезать записываемые данные, о чём прямо написано в его документации.

Comment: @andreymal, вы о pipe и нескольких байтах из вопроса или *вообще*?

Comment: @avp вероятно, это не относится к UDP, так как в нём пакеты таки есть (впрочем, гарантий неделимости в документациях Linux и FreeBSD я почему-то не увидел)

Comment: А вот что действительно стоит упомянуть, так это опцию O_DIRECT, которую завезли в Linux 3.4 для pipe2 и которая «performs I/O in "packet" mode». Правда, похоже, кроме линукса её больше нигде и нет

Comment: @andreymal, вероятно я не правильно понял вопрос и автора интересуют "настоящие" пакеты (как в UDP). Тогда ответьте ему указав на `pipe2(..., O_DIRECT)`.